# How to add a method to an existing object instance at runtime in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

In Javascript I could do this.

```
var a = {};
a.f1 = function(){};
```

How can I do this in Ruby?

---

Update.

In JS code, `a` is an object instantiated without class. And `function(){}` is an anonymous function, and `a.f1 =` adds the function to the object instance. So the function is bound to the instance only, and nothing is related to the class or similar definitions.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ruby and JS's object models are very different, but a direct translation may look like this:

```
a = Object.new
def a.f1(x) 
  2*x
end

a.f1(5) #=> 10
```

You can also use the Ruby's eigenclass:

```
class Object
  def metaclass
    class << self; self; end
  end
end

a = Object.new    
# Also: (class << a; self; end).send(:define_method, :f1) do |x|
a.metaclass.send(:define_method, :f1) { |x| 2*x }
```

A warning note: you'll see this kind of code in meta-programming/monkeypatching/... but it's not usual when writing "normal" code, where other techniques (module mix-ins, mainly) apply.

Comment: Does second one add the block code to the `Object` class as a instance method `f1`?

Comment: you don't need the metaclass stuff. just use `foo.class.send(:define_method, :bar) do ... end`

Comment: @Edmund, but this would add method :bar to all instances of the class, I understood the OP wanted to add it only to a specific instance.

Answer (score 5):

There's difference between JavaScript and other languages because JavaScript does inheritance in another way. So here's couldn't be direct analogue.

Let's pretend that {} is the A class in ruby and you create object from it

```
class A
end

a = A.new
```

And f1 function seats in some module B

```
module B
  def f1
    puts "you've extended your object"
  end
end
```

Now you can do what you want in similar way

```
a.extend(B)

a.f1 #=> "you've extended your object"
```